Gradle doesn't fail if BOM doesn't exist
I have my own BOM to manage my organization's dependencies. I would like the Gradle build to fail immediately if BOM doesn't exist. However, if I reference a BOM version which doesn't exist anywhere, the Gradle build doesn't seem to notice, will continue and will only fail when it cannot find the actual dependency. For example
dependencies {
  implementation(platform('com.mycompany:platform-bom:10.1.0'))
  implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
...

In case the version 10.1.0 of my BOM doesn't exist anywhere,  will get the error that
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':services:myservice:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:.
     Required by:
         project :services:myservice

instead of error that BOM isn't found. I am wondering if there is away to fail the build if the BOM isn't found.
